# Scraper for parsing email-ID using email sending button

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, web-scraping, email

I've written a script in python with POST request which is able to send email using send button and then catch the response of that email and finally parse the ID from that. I don't know whether the way I did this is the ideal one but it does parse the email ID from this process. There are 4 email sending buttons available in that webpage and my script is able to scrape them all. Here is what I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

main_url = "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=pizza&location=London&scrambleSeed=2082758402"

def main_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36'}).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@class='businessCapsule--callToAction']"):
        title = titles.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"btn-blue")]/@href')[0] if len(titles.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"btn-blue")]/@href'))>0 else ""
        process_page(title.replace("/customerneeds/sendenquiry/sendtoone/","").replace("?searchedLocation=London",""))

def process_page(number):   
    link = "https://www.yell.com/customerneeds/sendenquiry/sendtoone/"
    payload = {'message':'Testing whether this email really works.','senderPostcode':'GL51 0EX','enquiryTimeframe':'withinOneMonth','senderFirstName':'mth','senderLastName':'iqbal','senderEmail':'habibrahman@gmail.com','senderEmailConfirm':'habibrahman@gmail.com','uniqueAdId':number,'channel':'desktop','ccSender':'true','marketing':'on'}
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.post(link, data = payload, headers = headers)
    items = response.json()
    item = items['emailToCustomerUUID']
    print(item)

main_page(main_url)
```

These are the four email IDs I've parsed from that webpage:

```
1. 468145be-0ac3-4ff0-adf5-aceed10b7e5e
2. f750fa18-72c9-44d1-afaa-475778dd8b47
3. d104eb93-1f35-4bdc-ad67-47b13ea67e55
4. 90d2db3b-6144-4266-a86c-aa39b4f99d9a
```

Post Script: I've used my fake email address and put it in this script so that you can test the result without bringing any change to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the few improvements I would apply:

- match the "Email" links directly via `//div[@class='businessCapsule--callToAction']//a[. = 'Email']/@href` XPath expression - note how I'm matching the link by `Email` text
- use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) to get the "id" number and extract that logic into a *separate function*
- make a "scraper" class to share the same [web-scraping session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and persist things like headers to avoid repeating them every time you make a request
- a better name for `process_page` would probably be `send_email`

Improved Code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
from lxml import html


def extract_id(link):
    """Extracts the search result id number from a search result link."""
    return urlparse(link).path.split("/")[-1]


class YellScraper:
    MAIN_URL = "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=pizza&location=London&scrambleSeed=2082758402"
    EMAIL_SEND_URL = "https://www.yell.com/customerneeds/sendenquiry/sendtoone/"

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36'}

    def scrape(self):
        response = self.session.get(self.MAIN_URL).text
        tree = html.fromstring(response)
        for email_link in tree.xpath("//div[@class='businessCapsule--callToAction']//a[. = 'Email']/@href"):
            self.send_email(extract_id(email_link))

    def send_email(self, search_result_id):
        payload = {'message': 'Testing whether this email really works.', 'senderPostcode': 'GL51 0EX',
                   'enquiryTimeframe': 'withinOneMonth', 'senderFirstName': 'mth', 'senderLastName': 'iqbal',
                   'senderEmail': 'habibrahman@gmail.com', 'senderEmailConfirm': 'habibrahman@gmail.com',
                   'uniqueAdId': search_result_id, 'channel': 'desktop', 'ccSender': 'true', 'marketing': 'on'}

        response = self.session.post(self.EMAIL_SEND_URL, data=payload)
        items = response.json()
        item = items['emailToCustomerUUID']
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = YellScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe for your invaluable suggestions and dynamic code. The xpath you used in your script is overwhelming. I can't still figure out how this portion "[. = 'Email']" works. A  one-liner explanation on how the xpath was built-upon will be very helpful for me to understand. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @SMth80 glad to help! The `.` generally refers to the string value of a current node, which for nodes with texts only is equivalent to `text()`. It is explained in a greater detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38240763/771848). Thanks for an another interesting problem.